# looping through parent child combination xml using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to xml, i want to looping through the below xml and save the records in the database. the below xml is parent child combination, parts as to be saved under respective parents. if the source field is M then there will be child item for that.

```
  <PARENT>
 <COMPONENT>
  <part>test1</part><source>M</source><ParentPart>parent</ParentPart>
  <SUBCOMPONENT>
   <part>test2</part><source>B</source><ParentPart>test1</ParentPart>
  </SUBCOMPONENT>

  <SUBCOMPONENT>
   <part>test3</part><source>M</source><ParentPart>test1</ParentPart>
   <SUBSUBCOMPONENT>
    <part>test4</part><source>B</source><ParentPart>test3</ParentPart>
   </SUBSUBCOMPONENT>
  </SUBCOMPONENT>

 </COMPONENT>

 <COMPONENT>
  <part>part1</part><source>B</source><ParentPart>parent</ParentPart>
 </COMPONENT>

 <COMPONENT>
   <part>part2</part><source>M</source><ParentPart>parent</ParentPart>
  <SUBCOMPONENT>
   <part>part3</part><source>B</source><ParentPart>part2</ParentPart>
  </SUBCOMPONENT>

  <SUBCOMPONENT>
   <part>part4</part><source>M</source><ParentPart>part2</ParentPart>
   <SUBSUBCOMPONENT>
    <part>part5</part><source>B</source><ParentPart>part4</ParentPart>
   </SUBSUBCOMPONENT>
  </SUBCOMPONENT>

 </COMPONENT>

</PARENT>
```

any help would be appropriated.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: I must have missed it, but is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: Do you have a Database, Databaseschema and do you know what kind of db components you're going to use?

Comment: I can take care of saving the values into data base but first of all i want to read the xml and put into the data reader or some thing. i have tables masterpart and childpart, all source M should save in master table with respect to their perticular parent and child will save in child table and there is parent child relationship in the tables

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of options here:
- if you have xml schema, use xsd.exe which generates classes you fillup with XmlSerializer.
- XmlDocument allows you to do XPath queries.
- consider XmlTextReader if your files are large and you need fast proccesing.